# Python Django- How do I read a file from an input file tag?

Tags: python, django

I don't want the file to be saved on my server, I just want the file to be read and printed out in the next page. Right now I have this.

```
(index.html)
    <form name="fileUpload" method="post">
        <input type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

And I'm trying to do something like this-

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        upload = request.POST.get('fileUpload').read()
        return render(request, 'directory/return.html', {'output': upload})
    else:
        return render(request, 'directory/index.html')
```

But obviously that just doesn't work. I want it to work for text files and csv files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, there are some things missing in your form which you will have to add.

To upload files using a form, you’ll need to **define the `enctype` as `"multipart/form-data"`** in the  `<form>` element. Also, the **file input element should have the `name` attribute** in it

**index.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/my/url/" method="post"> # define the enctype
    <input type="file"  name="my_uploaded_file"/> # define a 'name' attribute 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then, in your views, you can access the uploaded file using [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) dictionary. As per `request.FILES` docs:

> Each key in `FILES` is the name from the `<input type="file" name="" />`.
>   Each value in `FILES` is an `UploadedFile`.

**You can access the uploaded file using `my_uploaded_file` key in the `request.FILES` dictionary.**

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_uploaded_file = request.FILES['my_uploaded_file'].read() # get the uploaded file
        # do something with the file
        # and return the result            
    else:
        return render(request, 'directory/index.html')
```

**Note:**

> `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST`
>   and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute
>   `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change your form:

```
<form method="post" action="/your/view/url/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="testing_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Next you'll get file in:

```
request.FILES['testing_file']
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer (Rahul Gupta's) worked perfectly fine for me! But here are some errors I encountered (I'm a newbie but maybe this can help someone)

---

```
**(TypeError: upload_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request')**
```

To solve it (and because I'm working with routes), at the very top, I didn't use: `def upload_file(request):` but:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
```

---

```
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FILES'**
```

To solve it, I realized I actually couldn’t use the `request.files` function because I forgot to install the requests library (and had some trouble doing so because I had to upgrade my PIP version), but I finally did, and then I had to import the `requests` module.

Here is the link that guide me through this because there's no way I could explain it better: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python

---

```
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FILES'** (Again!!!)
```

I thought I figured out this error, but it came back! After reading many different websites I realized `requests.FILES` isn't working, but instead it’s `requests.files` (no caps!). I'm not sure if this was an update but many people had this problem.

Hope this helped!!! :)