# The form is not uploading any data on data base

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, phpmyadmin

I am trying to make a form that uploads data and a pic on the SQL database the HTML form is working fine but when I press submit it say the page isn't working and doesn't insert any data on the table can u plz help and check what is the problem with my code

Here is my python code
#main.py

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
import urllib.request
import os
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from Dbaconnection import dbaconnect
     
app = Flask(__name__)
     
app.secret_key = "cairocoders-ednalan"

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'
  
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
  
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
  
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
      
  
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route('/webproject', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_image():
 
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        data=request.form
        db = dbaconnect();
        dbcursor = db.cursor()
        print(data['file'])
        dbcursor.execute("INSERT INTO webproject(name,Address,Photo) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",(data['Name'],data['Address'],data['Photo'],))
        db.commit()
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed below')
        return render_template('index.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are - png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)
    
  
@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and here the  HTML form code
#index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Database upload form</title>

    <!-- Font Icon -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {{url_for('static',filename='fonts/material-icon/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css')}}">

    <!-- Main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/style.css')}}">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="main">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="signup-content">
                <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}">
                <form method="GET","POST" id="signup-form" class="signup-form" action = '/webproject' enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
                    <h2>Assignment</h2>
                    <p class="desc">Enter The Student Data To store</span></p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="Name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-input" name="Address" id="address" placeholder="Your Address" />
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="costom-file">
                    <label class="custom-file-lable" for="image">file input</label>
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="Photo" name="Photo" VALUE="upload a file" />
                  </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="upload on db" id="submit" class="form-submit submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- JS -->
    <script href="{{url_for('static',filename='vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script href="{{url_for('static',filename='js/main.js')}}"></script>
</body>
<!-- This templates was made by Colorlib (https://colorlib.com) -->

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't put multiples `method` in html `form` tag. you can only choose one either `get` or `post`
2. Your backend code for getting `file` input from html form is invalid

in your html form, you said:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="Photo" name="Photo" VALUE="upload a file" />
```

but in your backend code:

```
request.files['file'] -> request.files['Photo']
```

as mentioned [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655704/python-django-how-do-i-read-a-file-from-an-input-file-tag)